# Add Control To the Designer of Active Report

Tags: c#, vb.net, activereports, grapecity

I know there are different ways to add controls in Active Report. I have found them on different web pages like:

```
this.Sections["groupHeader1"].Controls.Add(txt);
```

But this is none of my Business I have to load the designer i.e. `GrapeCity.ActiveReport.Design.Designer` with the some controls. I want to add these controls from my code behind. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking with the End User Designer and want to add controls to section based report sections then you will need to cast the End User Designer report using the SectionReport class and access its sections accordingly. For example check the following code which adds a textbox to the "Detail" section of the report on a button click:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox txtBox = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox();
        txtBox.Text = "Hello World!";
        txtBox.Location = new Point(1, 1);
        txtBox.Size = new SizeF(2, 0.5f);
        ((GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport)reportdesigner.Report).Sections["Detail"].Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
```

Here reportDesigner is the name of the designer control. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as the answers are very rare for ActiveReports. I have got a solution by studying the documentation. I am going to post my solution as well.

Comment: Your answer looks batter than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by having a new `SectionReport` and adopting the `Designer.Report` in it. Now adding the control in `SectionReport` means, adding the control in `Designer.Report`. This is what I think of the following solution as it worked for me.

```
Dim sr As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport()

sr = Me.reportdesigner.Report
''Adding Detail section
sr.Sections.Insert(1, New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail())
sr.Sections(1).BackColor = Color.PeachPuff
sr.Sections(1).Height = 1.5F

Dim lbl2 As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Label()

lbl2.Location = New PointF(0, 0.05F)
lbl2.Text = "Category ID"
lbl2.Alignment = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.TextAlignment.Center
lbl2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
sr.Sections(1).Controls.Add(lbl2)
```

Report me if any issue is there in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which you can put in load event of Form.

```
  GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport sectionReport = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport();
    sectionReport.Sections.Add(GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.SectionType.Detail, "Body");
                GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox MyTextBox = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox();
                MyTextBox.Text = "My Runtime Text";
                MyTextBox.ShrinkToFit = true;
                MyTextBox.DataField = "ID";
                sectionReport.Sections[0].Controls.Add(MyTextBox);
```